# data file re-organisation

Tags: command-line, python, perl, text-processing

I have a .data and I need to re-organise it so that 3 consecutive lines are joined together in a single line. Just to be clear, I have the following
...

```
D611102 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,
C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,
A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,
FX = -0.355305, FY = 0.857782, FZ = 0.282590;
```

...and so on

and I need all that in a single line:

```
D611102 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 ...
```

and I need it through all the document. Is there a fast way to do so?

The other difficulty is that all the info to be joined are sometimes in 3 different lines and sometimes in 2 or 4 different lines. The only thing I have is that each line is identified by a D.... 
Is it possible to do it? How?

Basically each new line should start with D611102 that is the node number. And I need a single big line with T = ..., C = ..., till FZ = .... ,etc.
Each full line must have all the data till the ;

To be more clear, I have the following:
...

```
   D611102 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,
     C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,
     A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,
     FX = -0.355305, FY = 0.857782, FZ = 0.282590;
    D611103 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,
     C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,
     A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,
     FX = -0.656518, FY = 0.656518, FZ = 0.282590;
```

... etc
...
And I need this:

```
D611102 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,FX = -0.355305, FY = 0.857782, FZ = 0.282590; (all in a single line)
D611103 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,FX = -0.656518, FY = 0.656518, FZ = 0.282590;
```

(all in a single line)
and so on for the whole document.

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify. Do you want all the data of the file one one, single, long line? Do you want every occurrence of `D` to be on a different line? What about the `Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001` in your example? Or is it that lines are defined as starting with a `D` and ending with a `;`? If so, can we be sure that there are no `;` in between?

Comment: Ok, basically each new line should start with D611102 that is the node number. And I need a single big line with T = ..., C = ..., till FZ = .... and yes, each full line must have all the info till the ;

Comment: Hi sande88 did you have the chance to try the options?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you basically want to remove all line breaks that don't occur directly after a `;`. If so, you can do:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!;)\s*\n/ /' file > newfile
```

Or, to edit the file in place, use `-i`:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(?<!;)\s*\n/ /' file
```

The above will make the changes to `file` and create a backup of the original called `file.bak`. To skip creating the backup just use `-i` alone, without an extension.

#### Explanation

The `-p` means "print every input line after applying the script given by `-e`. The `s///` is the substitution operator. Its general format is `s/pattern/replacement/` and will replace `pattern` with `replacement`.

In this case, `pattern` is 0 or more whitespace characters (`\s*`) followed by a newline (`\n`) which are not preceded by a `;`. The `(?<!foo)bar` construct is a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), it will match `bar` if the previous characters are not `foo`. Therefore, the script above will remove all newlines that aren't just after a `;`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I think your answer solves my problem! Right now I don't have my pc with ubuntu with me, but this evening i'll try your solution. Is there another way for doing so also in windows? With notepad++ or something similar?

Comment: @sarde88 no idea, I don't use Windows. I think that notepad++ has good regex support though, you might try using the regex there. However, note that if you open the file in Windows, you will change the line endings to `\r\n` instead of `\n`. You don't want to do that. If you find that it doesn't work after having opened the file on Windows, use this instead: `perl -pe 's/(?<!;)\s*\r*\n/ /' file > newfile`.

Comment: ok thanks, this evening I'll try. One tipp: how do you get "proficient" in using the linux terminal? I've been using it for like 2 years, but I am only familiar with basic commands (change directory, create folders, move file, ...). For the rest, unfortunately, I look for the code in internet and use it...but I don't see any improvement in my skills. Any useful book?Just practice and practice? Thanks again.

Comment: @sarde88 actually _using_ it (if you only know those simple commands, you're not really using it) and being curious. For every command you run, read `man command` to learn how it works. Read a basic scripting tutorial. It also helps to have been using Linux at home and work for ~17 years or so :)

Answer (score 1):

The script below should do the job. Since it reads per line, it should be relatively fast on larger files, but didn't test it on a large file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]

s = ""

with open(f) as lines:
    for l in  lines:
        if l.startswith("D"):
            print(s+l.strip(), end = "")
            s = "\n"
        else:
            print(l.strip(), end = "")
```

#### Use it

- Copy it into an empty file, save it as `combine_lines.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/combine_lines.py <.data_file>
  ```

#### Explanation

The script reads the lines, line by line. If the line starts with a `D`, else the line is simply printed after the existing line, *except* for the first line.

#### Test:

```
D611102 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,
A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,
FX = -0.355305, FY = 0.857782, FZ = 0.282590;
D611102 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,
A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,
FX = -0.355305, FY = 0.857782, FZ = 0.282590;
```

becomes:

```
D611102 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,FX = -0.355305, FY = 0.857782, FZ = 0.282590;
D611102 = 'SVM_PRS_Hydr_L01', T = 0.0,C = 3.341441E-006 * Cp_SVM_PRS_Pi001 * Dens_SVM_PRS_Pi001,A = 0.007425, ALP = 1.000000, EPS = 1.000000,FX = -0.355305, FY = 0.857782, FZ = 0.282590;
```

---

### EDIT

#### or,

as suggested by @terdon, using the ending ";" as a trigger, which gives us the opportunity to skip the `s =` trick:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]

with open(f) as lines:
    for l in  lines:
        l = l if l.endswith(";\n") else l.strip(); print(l, end = "")
```

#### Comparing Perl to python

On a relatively large file, 550MB, 9006121 lines:

Perl:

```
$ time perl -pe 's/(?<!;)\s*\n/ /' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/data_large' > '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/data_large2'

real    0m27.171s
user    0m25.536s
sys     0m1.054s
```

Python:

```
time '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pscript_9.py' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/data_large' > '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/data_large2'

real    0m15.235s
user    0m13.806s
sys     0m1.279s
```

On a smaller file, 51KB, 838 lines:

```
$ time perl -pe 's/(?<!;)\s*\n/ /' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/data_small' > '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/data_small2' 

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Python:

```
$ time '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pscript_9.py' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/data_small' > '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/data_small2' 

real    0m0.033s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m0.011s
```

The bottom line is that if you have bigger files, `python` might be what you'd like to use, if you have many, smaller files, `Perl` is the better option.

Comment: You might want to use `endswith(";")` (or whatever the pythonspeak for that is) instead of `startwith("D")`. The OP is not ver clear but I think that the only thing we can be sure of is that lines start with D and end with `;`. There is no guarantee that one of the bad line breaks won't have been inserted after a `D`.

Comment: @terdon of course, much smarter, since it skips the `s=` section. Will edit in an hour.